# How to make a classifier using LSTM in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I need to make a classifier in Keras which uses LSTM layers as the data is a time series.
The output should be a class which can have one of 4 values.
The labels for the training data are stored in a one-hot encoding of 4 columns.
Here is what I have so far, which isn't working?

[image: code]

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Epoch 1/20
```

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 model.fit(lxtrain, lytrain, epochs=20, batch_size=1000);

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
976             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 977               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
978             else:
979               raise

ValueError: in user code:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:788 run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:758 train_step
    self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:408 update_state
    metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py:90 decorated
    update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py:177 update_state_fn
    return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py:618 update_state  **
    matches = ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py:3307 sparse_categorical_accuracy
    y_true = array_ops.squeeze(y_true, [-1])
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py:538 new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py:4379 squeeze
    return gen_array_ops.squeeze(input, axis, name)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py:10173 squeeze
    "Squeeze", input=input, squeeze_dims=axis, name=name)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:750 _apply_op_helper
    attrs=attr_protos, op_def=op_def)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:592 _create_op_internal
    compute_device)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:3536 _create_op_internal
    op_def=op_def)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:2016 __init__
    control_input_ops, op_def)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1856 _create_c_op
    raise ValueError(str(e))

ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 4 for '{{node Squeeze}} = Squeeze[T=DT_FLOAT, squeeze_dims=[-1]](remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze)' with input shapes: [?,4].
```

How can I make this work?

Thanks and regards

Comment: When I try to fit the model with the labels in a single column without one-hot encoding I get the following error:

Comment: UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported
  [[node Cast_1 (defined at <ipython-input-56-ff76f53150ab>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_9831]